# Recompile huge air project

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air

I decompiled the League of Legends (from here on referred to as LoL) client today, in it i made a simple change. Now that i need to recompile, i have hit a problem.

I am not amazing at flash, so this will probably be very basic.

The launcher for LoL is a huge adobe air (possibly some flex there too) project, where everything is interconnected, and split into multiple files. This becomes a problem for me because i want to recompile only a single part of this program.

When i do the usual file>publish to compile it i get 168 errors, all of them pertaining to the fact that all the classes should be movieclips. Which they aren't, since they are supposed to be instances of other "files"

A sample error:

```
<stuff>\mod_man.dat\CRLRoomEveIcon.as, Line 1    5000: The class 'CRLRoomEveIcon' must subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip' since it is linked to a library symbol of that type.
```

A sample file:

```
package 
{
    import mx.flash.*;

    dynamic public class CRLRoomEveIcon extends UIMovieClip
    {

        public function CRLRoomEveIcon()
        {
            addFrameScript(0, this.frame1);
            return;
        }// end function

        function frame1()
        {
            stop();
            return;
        }// end function

    }
}
```

How do i make flash (CS 5.5) aware of these dependencies, so it will stop giving me errors, and just compile already?

ps. the result of these errors is that NO actionscript is included in the swf.

UPDATE:
right after i posted this, i came up with a new keyword to plonk into google, and google returned with what i assume is the reason it's not working, flex is not loaded, how do i load flex into flash?

Comment: I don't know anything about "League of Legends" but do you the appropriate IP rights in place to decompile their project?  If people believe you are doing nefarious deeds; they may be less liable to want to help you.  For a beginner, I do not recommend trying to use Flex from inside Flash Pro.  I'd recommend using Flash Builder or the command line Flex SDK.

Comment: I do not own any IP right, which is why i decided to post a fairly generic piece of code, What i'm doing with the code is for my own entertainment, i'm decompiling it for fun, with no malicious intent ;) I have no idea how to use any of those 2 tools, but google will teach me.

Comment: My main problem is that the swf file i decompiled also includes images, sprites and text, all packed in an fla file, which to my knowledge can't be compiled with flex.

Comment: While I, personally, am not against decompiling code for education purposes; I was under the impression it goes against many Intellectual Property laws worldwide.  An FLA file is a source file for Flash Professional.  If you have that, I'm not sure I understand why you'd need to decompile anything.

Comment: The FLA file is what the decompiler produces, decompiling the binary, to return the source. It might be against IP right, but riot (the developers of LoL) is usually very friendly as long as you don't do anything stupid. What i'm having trouble with is recompiling, i've tried everything i can, even installing the flex component addin, but the error remains.

Comment: How did you decompile the project? You can [use this project to add patches](https://github.com/Snowl/LoLEnhancementSuite) to lol launcher. But I need to see the code to actually change anything...